# “Submit is not a function" in JavaScript with a Django form

Tags: javascript, django

I wrote a Django form:

```
class EditTaskForm(forms.Form):
    taskContent = forms.CharField(label="内容", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'code'}))
```

And here's my JavaScript code in a HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  button = document.getElementById("login");
  button.onclick = function() {
    var f = document.getElementById("code");
    f.submit();
  }
</script>
```

But something went wrong and the error says:

```
f.submit is not a function
```

There's some solutions saying that maybe the method `submit()` is overridden, but I checked the whole HTML file, this is the only place the word `"submit"` is used.

And now I've got no idea what's going on.

Comment: Well `f` is here *not a `<form>`), it is an `<input>`. But why don't you make the `login` button a `<button type="submit">` In that case, there is no reason to do all this magic?

Answer (score 0):

`f` need to be a `<form>`, in your case it is a `<input>`. Just change:

```
var f = document.getElementById("code");
```

to:

```
var f = document.getElementById("whatever_your_form_id_is");
```